# Middlemanapp fails build over SASS error

Tags: rubygems, sinatra, middleman

I have a git controlled middleman app across two work machines. Identical copies of ruby and all gems updated. Middleman Server works just fine on both machines and Build works fine on one of the machines - but if I run build on the second dev machine it errors over an undefined sass variable in a partial. The partial is included with the correct syntax I believe ( just 'name') and is file named with _name.scss

Again - build passes on machine A but fails on machine B with identical ruby and gem setups (in theory).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Make the smallest possible test case that can reproduce the error, e.g., the variable declaration and evaluation. `@debug` statements can show values and file locations.

Make sure you're running `bundle exec middleman build`.

If sass can't find a partial it should tell you so (a different error).

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck running `bundle exec middleman build --verbose` as this should present more information to go on.